# Linux terminal, npm install ETIMEDOUT

Tags: linux, npm, npm-install, etimedout

I installed nodeJs and npm using nvm, that went perfectly, then I notice that a newer version of npm was available so i try

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

But then it just stays as like that, it's like it does not start never, so I try another command and this happens

```
npm install -g n
```

Same thing, noting happens.

Trying and trying I manage to get the following error:

```
/home/jonathan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.1/bin/npx --yes --package @angular/cli ng new untitled --defaults
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1123:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/jonathan/.npm/_logs/2022-12-28T05_07_38_682Z-debug-0.log
Done
```

So searching on the internet I found the url npm uses to attempt the installs the following:

> registry.npmjs.org <

I tried then:

```
ping registry.npmjs.org
```

Same as above, it does nothing, it suppose to show some info every few seconds but nothing happens so y put the url in a browser and it works

```
{"db_name":"registry","engine":"couch_bt_engine","doc_count":3313520,"doc_del_count":332,"update_seq":31421891,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"sizes":{"active":69891815727,"external":214417993712,"file":70327402736},"disk_size":70327402736,"data_size":69891815727,"other":{"data_size":214417993712},"instance_start_time":"1672130582611333","disk_format_version":7,"committed_update_seq":31421891,"compacted_seq":31421548,"uuid":"3a4ad341a4111dd254daa731f37b37ae"}
```

That's what it shows.

So. I don't know what it's going on, I'm not using any proxy or firewall. Need some help here.

Update... I try using wifi not wired connection and it works, so the problem appears to be wired connection

Comment: I have 300Mbit/s connection, just in case you ask

Comment: using VPN? f yes, try without it

Comment: Sounds you have network issues, so it's not really a programming related question anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Solution remains on network configuration, as Robert says its not related to programming so I'm marking this as answer. Thank any who try to help